# What is an example of a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above that does not contain its least upper bound?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds, lattice-orders

What is an example of a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded
above that does not contain its least upper bound? This is an on-a-review sheet for my final. I thought the completeness axiom stated that any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above has an upper bound. Can anyone explain?

Comment: $(0,1)$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: The completeness axiom says it “has” a supremum. The possessive there doesn’t mean this supremum belongs to the set, but rather that there is a number which exists and logically belongs to / is associated to that set. So, plenty of sets “have” a supremum but *do not contain* this supremum

Answer (score 4):

The completeness axiom says that any nonempty real subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound (supremum), called $\sup S$. However, the completeness axiom does NOT require that the supremum of $S$ actually be an element of $S$, it only requires the supremum to be a real number.

So, using the example from [@David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451193/what-is-an-example-of-a-nonempty-subset-of-r-that-is-bounded-above-that-does-not#comment9321915_4451193) above, the set $S = (0, 1)$ consists of all real numbers greater than 0 and less than 1. $S$ therefore doesn't contain 1 itself, but $1 = \sup S$. To prove this, note that if $0 < x < 1$, then $\frac{1+x}2$ (the number halfway between x and 1) is a member of $S$ yet is greater than $x$. Therefore, no such $x$ can be an upper bound of $S$.